# combine ggplot2 and share y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data for male and female factors
male_data <- data.frame(factors = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        values = c(10, 15, 12, 8))

female_data <- data.frame(factors = c("B", "C", "E", "F"),
                          values = c(13, 11, 9, 16))

# Plot for male data
male <- ggplot(male_data, aes(x = values, y = factors)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Male Factors", x = "Values", y = "Factors") +
  theme_minimal()

# Plot for female data with shared y-axis
female <- ggplot(female_data, aes(x = values, y = factors)) +
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Female Factors", x = "Values", y = "Factors") +
  theme_minimal()

cowplot::plot_grid(male, female)
```

[image: combined plots]

How can I make that the Y axis go from A to F, and align in both graphs, in a way that when the letter is unique in only one group (male or female: A,D,E,F) the group that is absent will not show a dot, while will be easy to compare B and C values in males and females, since is present in both graphs.

Comment: use `facet_*` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offering an alternative utilising `ggplot2::facet_wrap()`.
Consider using the argument `scales = "free"`.

```r
male_data <- data.frame(factors = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        values = c(10, 15, 12, 8))
female_data <- data.frame(factors = c("B", "C", "E", "F"),
                          values = c(13, 11, 9, 16))
df <- rbind(male_data, female_data)
df$sex <- as.factor(rep(c("Female", "Male"), each = 4L))

library(ggplot2)
df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = values, y = factors, colour = sex)) +
  geom_point(size = 3L) +
  scale_color_manual(values = 
                       c("Female" = "red","Male" = "blue")) +
  facet_wrap(~sex) +
  labs(x = "Values", y = "Factors", colour = "Sex") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

in the initial code, both plots were created independently, with their own levels of factors. Some factors had missing values in one dataframe but not the other; for instance, factor A was missing in the female data but present in the male data, and vice versa for factor E. This discrepancy caused the misalignment in both plots.

To address this issue, you can create a common y-range variable, and apply this range to both plots using the scale_y_discrete() function and you have to set the limits parameter to the y_range variable you created and the alignment problem will be resolved.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

# Sample data for male and female factors
male_data <- data.frame(factors = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        values = c(10, 15, 12, 8))

female_data <- data.frame(factors = c("B", "C", "E", "F"),
                          values = c(13, 11, 9, 16))

# Define the common Y-axis range
y_range <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

# Plot for male data
male <- ggplot(male_data, aes(x = values, y = factors)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Male Factors", x = "Values", y = "Factors") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = y_range) +  # apply y_range
  theme_minimal()

# Plot for female data with shared y-axis
female <- ggplot(female_data, aes(x = values, y = factors)) +
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Female Factors", x = "Values", y = "Factors") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = y_range) +  # apply y_range
  theme_minimal()

# Combine the plots
cowplot::plot_grid(male, female)
```

Now, both plots share a consistent y-axis range, ensuring proper alignment and facilitating easy comparison of factors between male and female datasets, even for levels that are not present in one but not the other dataset as seen below:
[Corrected plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDbeE.png)